# How/Can I Send an Email in BizTalk with an Excel attachment?

Tags: c#, excel, biztalk, email, spreadsheetml

I have transformed my data into an XML (SpreadsheetML) that can be opened with Excel and then saved manually as an xlsx file.  I can do the transformation into XML within BizTalk and I thought I could load and then save the XML into an Excel file.  I would then need to attach on an email.  Anyone know if this is possible?

What method has anyone used to convert the XML into an Excel workbook?
Can the Excel Workbook be returned to an Orchestration so it can be used in the dynamic email?